# A linear/logarithmic algorithm to find the minimum element in array after some operations on the array

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

The question goes as follows:
Given an array of size `n`, we can perform `k` operations on it. In each operation any element can be divided into two numbers `a` and `b`, such that `(a+b)` is the previous element, and the new number of elements is `n+1`. Then what is the minimal number we can obtain as the maximum element of the array?
Eg:
Suppose `n=3` and `k=2`
Array given by:
`3 3 4`
after one operation:
`3 3 2 2`
after second operation:
`3 1 2 2 2`
Hence the answer is `3` as it is the minimum value possible for the maximum of the array.
I was trying to come up with an algorithm for this, but every algorithm was `O(n^2)`. I was thinking of checking if it is possible for every number till the maximum element of the array=>`n^2`. 
The algorithm which I thought of is taking `i=1` to `i=k`, where I check whether a solution of `i` as a result is possible or not. `i` is possible when every number greater than `i` is divided to groups. For example, take a number `x`. `x` can be divided into `x/i` groups of `i` and another group `x%i` (if `!=0`). If the no. of groups is `y`, we need `y-1` operations. The first `i` I get is the answer.
Is there a better algorithm possible for the problem.

Comment: As far as I can see, the logic is to find out the max number in the array, if it is not the first one, split it (for even : divide by two; for odd : divide by two and add one to the left (a) rather than b) and keep repeating the process till iteration of `k` times.

Comment: @KaushikNP The complexity is `O(knlogn)` in such a case.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking of python at the time. For finding the max element itself another loops comes into picture in C. So yeah, won't work out.

Comment: @KaushikNP: Even splits aren't always optimal. For example, if you go for even splits with an initial array of `{6}` and 2 splits, the first split gives `{3, 3}` and the second gives `{3, 2, 1}`, but the optimal result is `{2, 2, 2}`.

Comment: @user2357112....exactly....that's precisely the reason I was getting a complexity of `n^2` every time

Comment: @user2357112, hadn't thought of this case. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Are a and b guaranteed to be positive?

Comment: @user2357112 What do you mean by "optimal"?

Comment: How do you know when to stop splitting? Why do you not split each `2` into two `1`s?

Comment: Instead of splitting elements one at a time by some rule, you could track *how many pieces each input will be split into*, and greedily increase the number of pieces assigned to the input that will produce the largest pieces under the current assignment. That'd produce actually correct results. It'd still be slow for large `k` values, but you can optimize it by jumping the algorithm to a starting point near the correct values. (I'd elaborate on how to perform the jump, and post an answer, but I think I'm getting sick.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice....take `a` and `b` to be positive and yes you can divide `2` to `1` and `1`. You stop after `k` operations. And optimal is explained in the question.

Comment: By tracking how many pieces each input will be split into, increasing the number of pieces a `6` will be split into from `2` to `3` represents a change from `3, 3` to `2, 2, 2`, rather than from `3, 3` to `3, 2, 1`.

Comment: Can you show a working algorithm (of any complexity) you came up with?

Comment: @n.m. The algorithm which I thought of is taking `i=1` to `i=k`, where I check whether a solution of `i` as a result is possible or not. `i` is possible when every number greater than `i` is divided to groups. For example, take a number `x`. `x` can be divided into `x/i` groups of `i` and another group `x%i` (if `!=0`). If the no. of groups is `y`, we need `y-1` operations. The first `i` I get is the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Can you [edit] the question itself and add this info, preferably with some kind of (pseudo)code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the *k*+1 greatest numbers in the array: complexity O(*n* log *k**). Convert them to rational number format: additional space O(*k**).
2. Make a heap of rational numbers: complexity O(*k**).
3. Increment the denominator of the greatest number in the heap, *k* times: complexity O(*k* log *k**).
4. The result is on the top of the heap. Round up to the next integer.

Total cost: time O((*n*+*k*) log *k**), space O(*k**), where *k** = min(*n*, *k*).

```
struct rational {
    int num;
    int denom;

    rational( int in_num = 0, int in_denom = 1 )
        : num{ in_num }, denom{ in_denom } {}
};

bool operator < ( rational lhs, rational rhs )
    { return static_cast<long>( lhs.num ) * rhs.denom < static_cast<long>( rhs.num ) * lhs.denom; }
bool operator > ( rational lhs, rational rhs )
    { return rhs < lhs; }

int max_after_divisions( std::vector< int > const & in, std::size_t k ) {
    std::size_t n = std::min( in.size(), k + 1 );
    std::vector< rational > v( n );
    std::partial_sort_copy( in.begin(), in.end(), v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<>{} );
    std::make_heap( v.begin(), v.end() );
    while ( k -- ) {
        std::pop_heap( v.begin(), v.end() );
        ++ v.back().denom;
        std::push_heap( v.begin(), v.end() );
    }
    return ( v.front().num + v.front().denom - 1 ) / v.front().denom;
}
```

Comment: (1) Don't have to sort the entire array, only the largest *k* elements (complexity *n log k*). (2) Why should `n` be involved in the calculations? What would you do with the array that only contains one number but it's 2^256?

Comment: @n.m. 1) Good point, with `std::partial_sort`. 2) That's what the second binary search is for. Also, unlike this answer, it needs to be done regardless. Still, it's a little simpler to code the two searches separately and avoid traversing the array repeatedly.

Comment: Sorry I meant m, not n. I don't think you need to search the number space, so no m or log m should be involved. Try to solve the same problem where inputs are rational numbers.

Comment: @n.m. Interesting. You seem to have some familiarity with the question. Also your name, *n.m.* :) . It sounds like my first approach using a heap was better, except instead of performing greedy integer division-by-two, the heap should store rational numbers.

Comment: At first I thought the rational numbers were a fancy mathematical trick, but they're just a way of assigning operations to numbers, no?

Comment: @m69 They're a way of avoiding division. Division operations suck. But you still need to renormalize them and/or avoid integer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do a counting sort of the input array.
Assign 1 operation to each of the k largest numbers (if a number is present x times in the input, assign x operations to it).
Set pointer A to the largest number with no operations assigned to it.
Keep a count of the number of re-assignable operations, that is initially zero.
Go over the numbers from high to low, and when you find a number that cannot be split into parts smaller than A using the operations assigned to it (or after adding re-assignable operations):
 - move A to the next number
 - remove A's assigned operations and add them to the count of re-assignable operations.
 - start checking from the end of the list again.

*(There are of course some fiddly details to be worked out.)*

This uses extra space for the counting sort and for storing the number of operations per number, but the time complexities of the different steps are something like O(n), O(k) and O(k^2), but I'm no expert at calculating complexity; (maybe the O(n) for counting sort is an illusion I got from using sparse associative arrays in javascript).